# Rails enum form text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

I have the following Rate model with a duration column that is an enum.

```
class Rate < ApplicationRecord

 enum duration: [ :thirtyminutes, :sixtyminutes ]
end
```

In the form to create a new rate, I have a select field that displays the enum keys.

```
<%= r.select :duration, options_for_select(Rate.durations.keys) %>
```

The options display as 'thirtyminutes' and 'sixtyminutes'.

My question is, how can I show the user '30 Minutes' and '60 minutes' instead?

Thank you.

Comment: What does `rate_types` have to do with your `duration` enum?

Comment: Sorry, wrong form field - edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work as i'm unable to test it, but could direct you in the right direction.

```
<%= r.select :duration, options_for_select('30 Minutes' => Rate.durations[0], '60 Minutes' => Rate.durations[1] ) %>
```